# VSCode Switch Off Editor History

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to make VSCode to use only current project files when using dialog for quick file open by name or we always have to clean editor history so recent files won't be showing there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, go to menu `File -> Preferences -> Settings` then in Search Settings input type `history`. `Search > Quick Open: Include History` will appear.

This setting:

`Search > Quick Open: Include History`

> Whether to include results from recently opened files in the file
> results for Quick Open.

Uncheck it to set it to `false`.